# cooking canned veggies in a Korean clay pot?

Tags: sausages, stews

I just acquired a Korean clay pot. One of the first things I made was some celery and chicken. Both turned out great but the celery was esp great. Right now, I have a surplus of canned vegetables of all sorts--spinach, peas, mixed veggies, etc.

Can any of these be made in a clay pot without losing texture? I was considering making a stew using canned veggies but was unsure if they would turn into mush if cooked in a clay pot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, as canned vegetables are already cooked, they can be mushy regardless of the vessel you cook them in. Depending on the desired result, I would add canned vegetables near the end of the stew's cooking time, especially peas and spinach e.g. in some sort of pie filling. You could cook them further, but expect vegetables like carrots to disintegrate.